# Resize image and maintain overlay positions

Tags: javascript

I am resizing an image in Javascript to have the image fill the parent container, with its correct aspect ratio. On top of that image i have items that i need to overlay on the image with specific coordinates.

- Original image size is: 654px X 418px
- On top of that image i overlay a few other canvas items at exact coordinates, 56px X 82px
- I resize the image, keeping correct aspect ratio of 1.56

---

- Image container to scale too: 1672px X 829px
- New image size with correct aspect ratio: 1297px X 829px
- **How do i calculate where the new canvas overlay coordinates are??**

Comment: That looks like maybe more of a image `scale to fit` than an image `scale to fill`. I think you want to find the new origin point of the image due to the "fitting" and then scale by the same ratio as the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the properties of the image element to determine the scaling factor to apply to the overlay items.

The intrinsic (unscaled) dimensions of an image are:

```js
const unscaledWidth = img.naturalWidth,
  unscaledHeight = img.naturalHeight;
```

The dimensions of the image as drawn are:

```js
const scaledWidth = img.offsetWidth,
  scaledHeight = img.offsetHeight;
```

The scaling factors are thus:

```js
const scaleX = scaledWidth / unscaledWidth,
  scaleY = scaledHeight / unscaledHeight;
```

Ref:

- [HTMLImageElement.naturalWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/naturalWidth)
- [HTMLImageElement.naturalHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/naturalHeight)
- [HTMLElement.offsetWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetWidth)
- [HTMLElement.offsetHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetHeight)